# C Array Extraction

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of integers. Let's assume

```
int a[5]={1,2,1,2,2};
```

I want to divide this array into two arrays by copying some elements of array `a` into some different arrays like `b[2]` and `c[3]`, such that `int b[2]` will contain `{1,2}` and `int c[3]` will contain `{1,2,2}`.

How can this be achieved using C?

Comment: You mean copy them into new arrays or just define new ways of referencing the parts of the original arrays?

Comment: What did you try?  Where did you run into difficulty?

Comment: Do you understand how to access the elements of an array? Do you understand how to assign to an element of an array? Why wouldn't just do the naive approach of looping and assigning elements of the destination arrays from the values of the source array? The `memcpy` approach described above is more efficient, but you don't give any impression that you even understand how to do it in a straight forward way. I'm tempted to downvote the question, but I really can't tell if you're being lazy or you really don't know anything about programming.

Comment: I got the solution by using memcpy..I was unaware of memcpy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can copy the data into new arrays using `memcpy`:

```
int b[2], c[3];
memcpy(b, a, sizeof(b));
memcpy(c, &a[2], sizeof(c));
```

However, if you do not need the results to be two independent arrays, and would not mind them being pointers, you can do this:

```
int *b= a, *c = &a[2];
```

These two pointers can be used in ways similar to arrays except for two important differences:

- `sizeof(b)` and `sizeof(c)` will represent the size of the pointer, not of the array
- The memory pointed to by the two pointers would not be independent of the original `a[5]` array.

If you print the content of memory pointed to by these two pointers, you would get the same results as if they were arrays:

```
for (int i =0 ; i != 2 ; i++) {
    printf("b[%d]=%d\n", i, b[i]);
}
for (int i =0 ; i != 3 ; i++) {
    printf("c[%d]=%d\n", i, c[i]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for great answer (posted it about 10 seconds before I did). `memcpy` is much less code than looping (or any other alternative).

Comment: I got the solution by using memcpy..I was unaware of memcpy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[5] = {1,2,1,2,2};
int b[2], c[3];

memcpy(b, a, sizeof(b));
memcpy(c, a + 2, sizeof(c));
```

Comment: I got the solution by using memcpy..I was unaware of memcpy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to reference the specified element of the original array:

```
int *b = a + 3; //  b[0] = a[3]
```